# Does $a^n b^m$ with $n, m \ge 0$ and $m \ne n$ fail the pumping lemma?

Tags: formal-languages

Does $a^n b^m$ with $n, m \ge 0$ and $m \ne n$ fail the pumping lemma?

I know it is not regular and that this can be demonstrated by using closure properties, but does the language pass the pumping lemma?

It seems to me that for any p I can pump either a or b (depending on which has a greater repetition count) without making n = m. But in an exam I am taking the answer key says it does not satisfy the pumping lemma.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the question?

Comment: It seems to me that for any p I can pump either a or b (depending on which has a greater repetition count) without making n = m.

Comment: Have you tried proving your suspicion? That's how we find out things in math.

Comment: Yes, I am scribbling a lot of stuff, but in the answer key from an exam it says this language does not pass the pumping lemma. So I am suspicious that the answer key might be incorrect.

Comment: The answer key is correct.

Comment: So my proof is wrong. I am thinking of a string that can not be pumped anyhow. Do you have any hint on it?

Comment: Yes. That method solves my question. But the other question's title is hard to search for.